# Parse JSON array and extract values for select list ID and Value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Thanks, I am passing in the array via json now and setting datatype to json, per your example as:

`{"car_make_id":"3","car_engine_type":"Non-Turbo Petrol"}{"car_make_id":"3","car_engine_type":"Non-Turbo Diesel"}`

But my script still refuses to append the select options and values?:

```
$("select#make").change(function(){
    $('#engine').find('option').remove().end(); //clear the engine ddl
    var make = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); //Need the value not the text - .Text()
    //alert(make);
    //do the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url:'get-engine.php',
        type:'GET',
        data:{engine:make},
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){                    
//var parsedjson = data=JSON.parse(data);  //no need if data:type json

$.each(data, function(index, item) {


    $("<option/>", {
        value: item.car_make_id,
        text: item.car_engine_type
    }).appendTo("#engine");
});


    }

});
});
```

Can't seem to find why it will not parse the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON structure is horrible so the real problem is to fix your JSON to be logical. Anyways
here's what you can try with the current one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'grabdata.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        type: make
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index, item) {

            for( var key in item ) {}

            $("<option/>", {
                value: key,
                text: item[key]
            }).appendTo("#engine");
        });
    },
    error: function (jxhr) {
        alert(jxhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DBg2L/1/

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much, and thank's for persisting with me to identify the root of my problem.

It;s members like yourself that make this community so valuable, especially for newer developers such as myself.

Comment: @Marc, just fix the JSON. because of the structure `for( var key in item ) {}` is needed and it just looks ugly.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with what I hope is the final issue! Will not seem to parse my array and append to select#engine?

Comment: @Marc, just do `console.log(data);` and see what was returned from the server. Also, are you sure you have only one element with the id engine? You cannot have multiple elements with the same id, which is why `select#engine` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi, according to console the response array returned from the server looks fine:

'{"car_make_id":"4","car_engine_type":"Turbo Diesel"}{"car_make_id":"4","car_engine_type":"Turbocharged Petrol"}'

And yes, just one #engine - i have amended to .engine

Thanks

Comment: @Marc, are you sure it's not an array. as in: `'[{"car_make_id":"4","car_engine_type":"Turbo Diesel"},{"car_make_id":"4","car_engine_type":"Turbocharged Petrol"}]'` Because only an array will work...

Comment: Ah! Thank you - that was it .... I was so focused on the jquery script I overlooked that ... yes, the array was not properly formed (missing []), so I ameded my php to:

'while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[] = $row;
 }'

and it is now correctly forming the array and returning it to the script. Thank you once again for your help ... it has been hugely helpful to me! :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, especially the part about "So need the ID value as "1" and list options as the names." But the following will populate the `select` element with `option` elements that take value of each property in `parsedjson` (`v`) as the value and the name of each property (`i`) as the value visible to the user:

```
$.each(parsedjson, function(i, v){
    $('select#engine').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + i + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry - I will elaborate on my example. My array will contain 2 rows, the engine type, and the engine manufacturer ID. I need to parse the array to have the engine manufacturer  ID as the select ID, and engine type as option value. So if my array is {"1":"1","Turbo Diesel":"Turbo Diesel","Turbocharged Petrol":"Turbocharged Petrol","Non-Turbo Petrol":"Non-Turbo Petrol"} I need the ID of "1" as value, and option as the engine types.

Comment: I still don't understand. Should the 1 be appended to the 'select#engine' selector, like `$('select#engine1')` ?

Comment: Hi, If the array sent via json is: 
{"4":"Turbo Diesel"}{"4":"Turbocharged Petrol"}{"4":"Turbo Diesel Max"}{"4":"Turbocharged Petrol Max"}

I need the select #engine to have its value and options set as <select value="4">Turbo Diesel</select> etc.

Iterated for the entire array.